# Using 'if' and 'for' to distinguish between numbers

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

There is a list called "G" and i am trying to replace any numbers above 5 with smile ":)" symbol and any number below 5 with ":(". i wrote this code, and expecting to only have five smiles however, the result is totally different and smile appears for all numbers. Thanks if anyone tell me what's wrong with this very simple and basic code.

```
`G <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
B <- for (i in 1:length(G))
if (any(G> 5)) {
print(":)")
}  else {
print(":(")
} `
```

Comment: You forgot the 'i' in your expression. `if (any(G[i] > 5))`. There are about 16 other things wrong with what you are doing, hopefully someone will talk you through what an R `list` is and how it differs from similar Python objects

Comment: Try `paste0(":", ifelse(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) >=5, ")", "("))`

Comment: Dont assign the for loop back to B, assign it within the loop (at the print stage in your loop). If you do this you need to define B before the loop. You dont need to use any(G), use G[[i]]. Instead of print , use B[i] <- ":)", and similarly for the less then condition. As a quick alternative without loop: `c(":(", ":)")[(unlist(G) > 5) + 1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The following points will help with the question and understanding of R for the future.

1. Lists vs. Vectors
2. For loops vs. Vectorization
3. `print` with assignment

**Lists**

In R, the `list` object is a special object that can hold other objects. They can hold almost anything, even other lists! Because they are so accepting of a mix of things, they are not equipped with all of the cool functions like vectors.

The vector is a simple R object with a common type. "Common type" means that the entire vector will either be numbers, or character values, or whatever other type we are using. If we created `c(1,"a")` we will have mixed a letter with a number. These two types will be forced to be only one type, `character`. The quantitative functions will not work with it anymore. But the list `list(1,"a")` will hold each as its own type.

In your case, you have a series of whole numbers. When the numbers are in a vector, we can apply many built-in functions to work with them that will not work with the generic list. Functions like `sum`, `mean`, and `sd`, are built to accept vectors. But they do not work with lists. We should change `G` to a vector:

```
G <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
#Or a bit shorter
G <- 1:10
```

**For loops and Vectorization**

In R, because vectors can only be of one type, many cool things are possible. I can do `G + 1` and R will add one to each element of `G`. It completed the whole thing without a loop. For conditional statements like yours we can vectorize also:

```
ifelse(G > 5, ":)", ":(")
```

**Print with assignment**

The `print` function can be saved but it is better to simply capture the output itself as is:

```
#Don't do
x <- print("hello")
#Do
x <- "hello"
```

Both work, but the second is more in line with R programming. The reason `B` did not save the output in your case is because you attempted to save the `for` loop itself. If you would like to save the output of a loop, do it within the loop since the output will be dumped upon completion.

To summarize, we can simplify to:

```
G <- 1:10
B <- ifelse(G > 5, ":)", ":(")
#[1] ":(" ":(" ":(" ":(" ":(" ":)" ":)" ":)" ":)" ":)"
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what Pierre mentioned: lists in R are different from Python. What you're looking for is a vector, you can read more about them [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Simple-manipulations-numbers-and-vectors). You can initialize a vector with `c()` like:

```
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

You can access a vector using it’s index by putting it in brackets `[]`. For example, in the vector `nouns <- c(“cat”, “dog”, “tree”)` using `nouns[2]` will return `”dog”`.

A functioning version of your code is:

```
G <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
for (i in 1:length(G)) 
{                   #missed loop curly bracket on this line
    if (G[i] > 5) {
        print(":)") #if you want to assign the output of a loop do it here
    } else {
       print(":(")
    } 
}
```

Edit: Pierre beat me to it! Leaving up but Pierre has a more thorough answer.